# Get information out of go block

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

I have the following ClojureScript code to make a POST request:

```
(defn perform-post [resource]
  "Performs a post and returns the body :)"
  (go (let [response (<! (http/post resource))]
        (:body response))))
```

When I make a call to a resource which returns a number

```
(js/console.log (perform-post post-create-recipe-url))
```

This prints:

> buf
> Object { buf={...},  n=1,  cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$=2,  
>       more...}
>   buf
> Object { head=1,  tail=0,  length=1,  meer...}
>   arr
>   ["6276677237104933520", undefined]

I want to obtain the "6276677237104933520" (the post body) information as a "return" value.

How can I accomplish this? I tried `<!!` but it does not work since it is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocking semantics (`<!!`) is not available on ClojureScript platform.

You can retrieve value from a channel only within `go` block:

```
(go (js/console.log (<! (perform-post post-create-recipe-url))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using an atom and assign the value to it. I need it later :).